# Gap right of the page (overflow-x:hidden issue)

Tags: scroll, overflow

There is a gap on the right side of my page probably 10px. I could fix it using oveflow-x:hidden for the html and body but if I do this, it disable the navbar effect

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 120) {
        $("#mainNav").addClass("scrolling");
    } else {
        $("#mainNav").removeClass("scrolling");
    }
});
</script>
```

That changes the navbar background-color when scroll down.

I tried `width:100%` as well, but it didn't work neither.

Could someone help me to eliminate the gap without affect this function?
Thank you

Comment: I started a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uffo6you/) but without knowing how you've styled the vertical navbar, I've no where to go.  You might give navbar width of 2vw, then rest of screen 98vw, but that's up to you.

Comment: There is no vertical navbar it is a normal navbar on the top of the page that is top fixed and change the color when scroll down. I dont see a reason for this gap.

Comment: does this jsfiddle accurately reflect your issue? http://jsfiddle.net/uffo6you/1/

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  See http://jsfiddle.net/uffo6you/3/  The CSS specificity ranking of `.scrolling` wasn't strong enough to override `#mainNav`.  Width and overflow shouldn't have any bearing on this at all.  Pls confirm?

```
<style>
#mainNav{
    height: 20vh;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
}
#mainContent{
    height: 200vh;
    padding-top: 20vh;
}

.scrolling{
    background-color: red !important;
}
</style>

<div id="mainNav">Top Navbar</div>
<div id="mainContent"> 
        Content goes here
</div> 

<script>
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll >= 80) { 
        $("#mainNav").addClass("scrolling"); 
    } else {
        $("#mainNav").removeClass("scrolling");
    } 
});
</script>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have, but I didnt get why there is a small gap on the right side of the page that doesnt appear on the screen unless I scroll to the right. I could fix it using overflow-x:hidden on the body, but if I do this the scroll function stops working. :(

Comment: Without seeing what the issue I don't know how I can help you.  I built a jsfiddle for you, and you've not commented on if it resembles your problem.  (Hint: update that jsfiddle to exhibit the same issue that you are seeing and then we can begin to help you...)  Another idea: look up my email address, send me the link to your site.  Happy to help you, but need some more info from you. Finally, what's your comfort level at working with Chrome developer tools?  You can pretty much see EVERYTHING that is going on there.